# Snowflake information_schema foreign key lookup

Tags: foreign-keys, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, information-schema

Is there a way to use the information_schema to identify a foreign key relationship?  I have a data integrity test method using the constraint view in conjunction with the columns view to dynamically build Pk and Uk test queries.

The issue I am having is that I can't find an information_schema view which I can use to build a Fk test query.  I found in a 10-year-old post a reference to INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE and CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE. However, I don't see those views today.  I am having to use the get_ddl() function which is causing issues when the role doesn't have permissions to sequences.  That is not an issue when queries are build using the information_schema views.

Referenced post: [How to find primary keys for all foreign keys in a DB using INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269197/how-to-find-primary-keys-for-all-foreign-keys-in-a-db-using-information-schema)

Comment: [TABLE_CONSTRAINTS View](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/table_constraints)

Comment: Hi Lukasz, That view tells me the foreign name, but it doesn't tell me the table's foreign key column name and the parent table's name and primary key column name.  Those are the attributes I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find the column names of foreign key constraints is to run:

SHOW IMPORTED KEYS;

This is run in context, but can also be used with the {IN (ACCOUNT | DATABASE | SCHEMA) } qualifiers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no **key columns usage** table in **Snow-Flake**:

Here are the ways :

**Approach 1  :** ( SQL Functions )

In snowflake first you **verify if a table really have some primary and foreign keys**, and then start writing some queries to work on that table.

if you don't verify this:

- **Hard** to find if the **query needs to be changed or the targeting table**
  need to be changed.

Query :

```
SHOW IMPORTED KEYS IN DB_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME ;
SHOW PRIMARY KEYS IN DB_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME;
```

*The above queries might return some empty results as there can be tables without primary and foreign key and that must be the only reason for the result returned to be empty*

**Approach 2:** ( Parsing the DDL Statement )

Here is the code :

[Java Method to Get Schema Details](https://snowflake.pavlik.us/index.php/2020/01/12/snowflake-relationships-java-utilities/)

- Understand this SchemaInfo class here and convert it to your preferred language.

Basically the approach in the code is :

```
SELECT GET_DDL('TABLE', 'SCHEMA_DETAILS.'TABLE_NAME'')
```

- Make sure whenever the **TABLE_NAME goes into the query add a additional set of quotes** to them else it might return back table doesn't exist.
- This fetches the **DDL** statement to *Create the same table*
- Parse the **DDL Statement** to understand the relationship.
- Logics to parse the string is all mentioned in the code